# How to debounce an AJAX call with VueJS?

Tags: lodash, vue.js

I am trying to debounce an AJAX call to only send it once, but unfortunately, it tells me that what I am passing it is not a function. Here is my code:

```
getItems: function(page){
  this.page = page;
  console.log(typeof(this.getBackendItems));
  _.debounce(this.getBackendItems(page), 500);
},
getBackendItems: function(page){
  this.$http.get("{{url('api/user/items')}}", {page : page}).success(function(response){
      this.items = response.data;
      this.last_page = response.last_page;
  });
},
```

Console.log says that getBackendItems is a function and still an error is thrown that not a function is passed to _.debounce() call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several things wrong with this:

#### Passing the function correctly

When you are trying to pass the function like this: `this.getBackendItems(page)` you are running it, so `_.debounce` does not receive the function, but the result of the function, which in this case, is a Promise object.

- `this.getBackendItems` passes the function
- `this.getBackendItems(page)` runs the function, and passed the result

But then, how do you tell it which arguments to use?

#### Correctly calling a debounced Function

Well, `_.debounce()` returns your original function, but wrapped with the debounce logic. So you cache it in a variable and execute that function with your desired arguments (`page`). So the syntactically correct Way to use debounce would be more like this:

```
getItems: function(page){
  this.page = page;
  console.log(typeof(this.getBackendItems));
  var debouncedFunction = _.debounce(this.getBackendItems.bind(this), 500); // properly bind the function so "this" is the vue component.
  debouncedFunction(page)
},
```

#### Debouncing the right function

But, that too won't work, because `getItems` itself is *not* debounced, so all this code will do is create many, many debounced functions, which will all fire once the 500ms is kicking in. Not a good idea.

Now my question is: how do you invoke this function? from a v-on:click? Then Vue got you covered:

#### Using Vue's debounce filter

```
<a v-on:click="getItems(page) | debounce 500">Some Link</a>
```

With that filter, you don't need to use `_.debounce` at all.

If you call this function some other way, let me know.

Edit: update due to comment feedback:

#### debounce function while counting the number of debounces

```
<a href="#"
  @click.prevent="getItems(page) | debounce 500" 
  @click="pageBuffer = pageBuffer +1">
  Click Me
</a>
```

JS:

```
var App = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
            page: 1,
      pageBuffer: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getItems: function(page) {
      this.getBackendItems(page + this.pageBuffer)
      this.pageBuffer = 0
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I am having a link <a v-on:click="getItems(page + 1) | debounce 500">Some Link</a>. Note the "page + 1". If I put the debounce filter on it - there won't be a change of the page, because it is placed inside the function that will be debounced. What I need, is to change the page immediately, but only load the last. Like if the user was on page 1 and clicked "next" 4 times, I need it to increment the "current_page" 4 times, so it would be 5, but only load the Items once - for the page 5.

Comment: I can't picture your exact situation, but you could use a second (not debounced) click handler to separately increase some buffer variable for the additional clicks. See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Linusborg/z14zmw16/

Comment: I thought of something like that myself, but putting two @click handlers seemed awkward for me. I'll go with it, if thats the only solution.

Comment: By the way, it is also great, that if the AJAX request fails, I can simply empty the page buffer, so that User will see that his clicks did not work :)

Comment: debounce filter has been removed in the new vue version.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that works for me:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" v-model="term">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      term: ''
    }
  },

  watch: {
    term(value) {
      this.search(value)
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.search = _.debounce(this.getBackendItems.bind(this), 1000)
  },

  methods: {
    getBackendItems(value) {
      console.log(value)
      // ...
    }
  }
}
</script>
```